# What would happen to the offspring of a Sharingan user and a Byakugan user?

Tags: boruto

If Sarada and Boruto got married, would their child get both Sharingan and Byakugan together, or would they get a fusion of these two instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is no fusion that we know of between the Byakugan and Sharingan. There have been instances where a mixed Hyuga awakened the Byakugan (Himewari) but none exists for the Sharingan. So it's hard to say but I'd put my money on the child have one or the other but not both.

Comment: Tbh, if Boruto and Sarada would get married, they'd have an extremely powerful child.

Sharingan + Byakugan + the great Chakra from Ashura would maybe form a new dojutsu/kekkai genkai.